# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3

Tags: java, arrays, exception, grid, cell

I'm trying to implement an **A* pathfinding algorithm** in java. So I create a grid and the user is requested to give its dimensions. The problem is that when **width!=height**, the program throws that exception. For example, a grid 5x5 is created without problems, whereas a grid 5x7 is not. I'm not sure how I can fix it. Here is the code:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
String rows =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame,
                "Συμπληρώστε τον αριθμό γραμμών του πλέγματος: \n",
                "Δημιουργία πλέγματος",
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
String cols =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame,
                "Συμπληρώστε τον αριθμό στηλών του πλέγματος: \n",
                "Δημιουργία πλέγματος",
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
int rowsnum = Integer.parseInt(rows); 
int colsnum = Integer.parseInt(cols);
transient Image buffer; 

GridCell gridCell[][] = new GridCell[rowsnum][colsnum];
public Map()
{
    super();
    //{{INIT_CONTROLS
    setLayout(new GridLayout(rowsnum,colsnum));
    //}}
    for(int i=0;i<rowsnum;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<colsnum;j++){
            System.out.println ("i=" + i + " j="+ j);
           gridCell[j][i] = new GridCell();
           gridCell[j][i].setPosition(new Point(j,i));
           add(gridCell[j][i]);
        }
    }
}
```

So as you see, I'm printing i and j in each loop to see where the problem is. And the result is (when I try to create a grid 3x5):

```
run:

i=0 j=0
i=0 j=1
i=0 j=2
i=0 j=3
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at Map.<init>(Map.java:32)
```

Where line 32 is:

```
gridCell[j][i] = new GridCell();
```

If anyone could help me I'd be grateful!

P.S. Ignore the greek! :-D

Comment: Immediately I suspect that i and j are the wrong way round somewhere

Comment: Switch i and j. Your array is defined as `new GridCell[rowsnum][colsnum];` but you are using it as `new GridCell[colsnum][rowsnum];`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this line you create a 2D array that is `rowsnum` by `colsnum`

```
GridCell gridCell[][] = new GridCell[rowsnum][colsnum];
```

However here you use it as if it is `colsnum` by `rowsnum`.

```
for(int i=0;i<rowsnum;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<colsnum;j++){
        System.out.println ("i=" + i + " j="+ j);
       gridCell[j][i] = new GridCell();
```

`i` goes between 0 and `rowsnum`(exclusive) but goes in the dimention that is between 0 and `colsnum`(exclusive)

`j` goes between 0 and `colsnum`(exclusive) but goes in the dimention that is between 0 and `rowsnum`(exclusive).

#### Solution

Either `i` and `j` are the wrong way round in `gridCell[j][i]` (and elsewhere) or `rowsnum` and `colsnum` are the wrong way round in `new GridCell[rowsnum][colsnum]`. Which it is depends on what you're trying to achieve, although conventionally its often array(rows,columns); implying i and j are the wrong way round

Comment: thank you that was the answer! I changed gridcell[j][i] to gridcell[i][j] and now it's working!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the way row index (i) and col injex (j) are used in your code. Please interchange i and j in the below code

```
       gridCell[j][i] = new GridCell();
       gridCell[j][i].setPosition(new Point(j,i));
       add(gridCell[j][i]);
```